# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting for cursor.execute(query, to_filter)

Tags: python, sql, api, flask, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to set up a simple flask application with GCP and after deploying the app for the API response when I search for the results based on ID, AUTHOR, PUBLISHED date, I am getting TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting for cursor.execute.
This is the function I am calling for those cases:

The error comes at this line:
**results = cursor.execute(query, to_filter) and I don't really understand which argument is not converted from the syntax SELECT * FROM entries WHERE id=?**

And it looks like this:

```
def filter_books():
conn = open_connection()
query_parameters = request.args
id = query_parameters.get('id')
published = query_parameters.get('published')
author = query_parameters.get('author')
with conn.cursor() as cursor: 
    query = 'SELECT * FROM entries WHERE'
    to_filter = []
     if id:
         query += ' id=?  AND'
         to_filter.append(id)
    
     if published:
         query += ' published=?  AND'
         to_filter.append(published)

     if author:
         query += ' author=?  AND'
         to_filter.append(author)

     if not(id or published or author):
         return "Page not found"

query = query[:-4] + ';'
results = cursor.execute(query, to_filter).fetchall() **(line 63 - error line)**
return jsonify(f_results)
```

The error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/srv/main.py", line 29, in api_filter
    return filter_books()
  File "/srv/db.py", line 63, in filter_books
    results = cursor.execute(query, to_filter)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 146, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 125, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

And this is the call of the function in the main file.py (lines 27-29)

```
@app.route('/api/v2/resources/books', methods=['GET'])
def api_filter():
    return filter_books()
```

For the following call of the API (**/api/v2/resources/books?published=2010**) query and to_filter have the following values:

**query = 'SELECT * FROM entries WHERE published=?'
to filter = [published]**

So the cursor.execute will look like this: **results= cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM entries WHERE published=?', published).fetchall()**

I have tried making to_filter a tuple, and every other topic on stackoverflow and on the google close to this but without success. It looks like a simple thing I am confusing or did not understand enough but after 6 hours of tries I need some help.

Thank you!

[main.py - function call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HZdA.png)
[db.py - function definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAmC8.png)

Comment: 1) Source code formatting is critical for Python programs. Edit your question and correct the indentation. 2) Post the entire Python error message. 3) If you are not including the entire source file, then specify which line number **def filter_books():** is so that we can match stack traces to line numbers. 4) Print the values of **query** and **to_filter** passed to **cursor.execute()** and include in your question.

Comment: Constructing queries by hand puts you at risk of SQL Injection  Attacks. https://xkcd.com/327/ jokes at it, but it's real. It's a little more work, but only a little, to using `flask_sqlalchemy`. Taking a quick run through the first parts of the Flask Mega Tutorial (https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) can save you a lot of grief.

Comment: Which database? Which library? Normally, I would use a `%s` instead of a `?` for Python.

Comment: I used Cloud SQL and pymysql, I used %s instead of ? and the error I got was that tuple object has no attribute append if i switched from ? to %s.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working, the modifications I did were to use %s instead of ? as John Hanley recommended and instead of calling .fetchall() on cursor.execute because it is impossible as the returned result is an int I called the .fetchall() on the cursor.

So the final code looks like this:

```
def filter_books():
conn = open_connection()
query_parameters = request.args
id = query_parameters.get('id')
published = query_parameters.get('published')
author = query_parameters.get('author')
with conn.cursor() as cursor: 
    query = 'SELECT * FROM entries WHERE'
    to_filter = []
    if id:
        query += ' id= %s  AND'
        to_filter.append(id)

    if published:
        query += ' published= %s  AND'
        to_filter.append(published)

    if author:
        query += ' author= %s  AND'
        to_filter.append(author)

    if not(id or published or author):
        return "Page not found"

    query = query[:-4] + ';'
    results = cursor.execute(query, to_filter)
    f_results=cursor.fetchall()
    return jsonify(f_results)
```